# having trouble on assignment operator

Tags: java, android, arrays

Hi I am doing a board game using AI in android.

I encountered a situation that doesn't make sense to me.

Code:

```
    for(int y = 0; y < BOARD_SIZE ; y++)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "before calling virtual mBoard:" + mBoard[y]);
    }

    virtualBoard = mBoard;  // int arrays
    virtualBoard[x] = nextMove(counter);

    for(int j = 0; j < BOARD_SIZE ; j++)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "before calling AIValue mBoard:" + mBoard[j]);
    }
```

When I make virtualBoard equals mBoard, I simply assign a array to another array, but how come the logs are different? Hows that possible?

Comment: If the arrays are different how come the logs would not be different ?

Answer (score 5):

> When I make virtualBoard equals mBoard, I simply assign a array to another array

No, you assign the value of `mBoard` to `virtualBoard`. The values of those variables aren't arrays - they're *references*. So after that assignment, the values of `mBoard` and `virtualBoard` are references to the same array. You then change the contents of that array in the subsequent statement.

It's a bit like this situation:

- I have a piece of paper with my home address on
- I take a copy of that piece of paper, and give it to Fred
- Fred goes to the address on the piece of paper and paints the front door green.
- When I get home, I see that my front door is green.

Comment: Thanks so much! I messed up the array with the primitive type :(

Answer (score 1):

```
    virtualBoard = mBoard;  // int arrays
    virtualBoard[x] = nextMove(counter);
```

In the first assignment, you are not creating a copy of your array. Rather a copy of a reference to your array.

So, your `virtualBoard` references the same array as `mBoard`. So, any changes you make to the `array` using any `reference` will be reflected for the other `reference`.